# Using JSR223 with Groovy in JMeter to run one thread group from within another

Tags: oop, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

Thread Group A: use challenge-response to generate user token.  Save as JMeter property.
Thread Group B: Run several samplers, one of which uses that token in a header.

Of course, the easy thing to do is run A, then B.

But let's say I want to use a "modular" approach and run only B.

I thought I recall seeing either in SO or Blazemeter that the JMeter object model allows one in a JSR223 Sampler to reference other samplers, even in another thread.

Other ideas also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSR223 Sampler cannot "call" another sampler neither from current nor in another Thread Group.

The only way of implementing this I can think of is storing the "common" logic as a [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and calling it where required using [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller)